# Dolphin Browser Stops Flash Player When Locked

Tags: adobe-flash, dolphin-browser

I'm using Adobe Flash player with Dolphin browser on my HTC One M8 which is working great, since I have Pandora One and I get the higher stream quality on the desktop site (192kbps instead of 64kbps), but the problem is that if I leave Dolphin or lock my phone screen, etc., then Flash player stops. Any way to allow Flash to play in the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Maxthon Web Browser,](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mx.browser&hl=en) which supports flash in the background. I think I saw some solution for getting Flash (YouTube specifically) to work with the screen off a while ago, but it required root.